# SharpZipLib Examine and select contents of a ZIP file

Tags: c#, zip, sharpziplib

I am using SharpZipLib in a project and am wondering if it is possible to use it to look inside a zip file, and if one of the files within has a data modified in a range I am searching for then to pick that file out and copy it to a new directory? Does anybody know id this is possible?

Comment: I am sure its possible.  You would have to open the archive and look at the contents of the collection of files.  Depending on if the last modification information is made public will determine if you will be able to everything else.  I don't the reason it won't be made public, the library SharpZibLib is based on allows for that, so it should also allow that.  Otherwise there is always other solutions that would allow for that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to enumerate the files of a zip file using SharpZipLib. You can also pick files out of the zip file and copy those files to a directory on your disk.

Here is a small example:

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(@"c:\temp\test.zip", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
  using (var zf = new ZipFile(fs))
  {
    foreach (ZipEntry ze in zf)
    {
      if (ze.IsDirectory)
        continue;

      Console.Out.WriteLine(ze.Name);            

      using (Stream s = zf.GetInputStream(ze))
      {
        byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
        // Analyze file in memory using MemoryStream.
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
          StreamUtils.Copy(s, ms, buf);
        }
        // Uncomment the following lines to store the file
        // on disk.
        /*using (FileStream fs = File.Create(@"c:\temp\uncompress_" + ze.Name))
        {
          StreamUtils.Copy(s, fs, buf);
        }*/
      }            
    }
  }
}
```

In the example above I use a `MemoryStream` to store the `ZipEntry` in memory (for further analysis). You could also store the `ZipEntry` (if it meets certain criteria) on disk.

Hope, this helps.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, much appreciated!!