# Read directory from a ZIP file

Tags: c#, sharpziplib

How would you read a directory in a ZIP file and return it as a local path with ICSharZipLib? Is it even possible?

I know how to make a streamreader from a file within the ZIP file, but after that I'm somewhat stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this can help,

> [SharpZipLib Examine and select contents of a ZIP file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8313791/sharpziplib-examine-and-select-contents-of-a-zip-file)

---

Recently I switched to [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) and I find it to be a much easier library to work with. They have an extensive [list of examples for C#](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CS-Examples&referringTitle=Examples).

Comment: Hmm, i cant really figure out how to use it:( sorry

Comment: Hmm, i can't figure it out really :( Any other help? please!

Comment: Did you try using the DotNetZip library?

Comment: Yeah, looked through some examples, I just found how to extract it:(